# DynamoDB data to S3 in Kinesis Firehose output format

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Kinesis data firehose has a default format to add files into separate partitions in S3 bucket which looks like : `s3://bucket/prefix/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/file.extension`

I have created event streams to dump data from DynamoDB to S3 using Firehose. There is a transformation lambda in between which converts DDB records into TSV format (tab separated).
All of this is added on an existing table which already contains huge data. I need to backfill the existing data from DynamoDB to S3 bucket maintaining the parity in format with existing Firehose output style.

**Solution I tried** :
Step 1 : Export the Table to S3 using DDB Export feature. Use Glue crawler to create Data catalog Table.
Step 2 : Used Athena's `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` Query to imitate the transformation done by the intermediate Lambda and storing that Output to S3 location.
Step 3 : However, Athena CTAS applies a default compression that cannot be done away with. So I wrote a Glue Job that reads from the previous table and writes to another S3 location. This job also takes care of adding the partitions based on year/month/day/hour as is the format with Firehose, and writes the decompressed S3 tab-separated format files.

However, the problem is that Glue creates Hive-style partitions which look like :
`s3://bucket/prefix/year=2021/month=02/day=02/`. And I need to match the firehose block style S3 partitions instead.
I am looking for an approach to help achieve this. Couldn't find a way to add block style partitions using Glue. Another approach I have is, to use AWS CLI S3 `mv` command to move all this data into separate folders with correct file-name which is not clean and optimised.

Comment: you can change prefix format on firehose side to match hive style partitions

Prefix: myPrefix/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/s3-prefixes.html#s3-prefix-examples

Comment: @Ajinkya Thats probably not an option as I have firehose data already being used from S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the solution I ended up implementing here in case it helps anyone.

I created a Lambda and added S3 event trigger on this bucket. The Lambda did the job of moving the file from Hive-style partitioned S3 folder to correctly structured block-style S3 folder.

The Lambda used Copy and delete function from boto3 s3Client to implement the same.
It worked like a charm even though I had like > 10^6 output files split across different partitions.